# Python writing SQLAlchemy queryobject to CSV

Tags: python, csv, sqlalchemy

I'm writing to a csv file in batches, and as I currently have it only the last 'batch' is being recorded on the file, whether I open the file with `'w'` or `'a'` flags. Here are my two attempts:

```
with open('testdump.csv', 'w') as csvfile:

    fieldnames = ['name', 'price']

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)        
    writer.writeheader()        

    for date in date_list:
        date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        q1 = db.session.query(...query goes here that depends on date...)

        rows = []
        for row in q1:
            rows.append(
           {
            'name': row.name,
            'price': row.price,
            }
         )

        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(dict(
            (k, v.encode('utf-8') if type(v) is unicode else v) for k, v in row.iteritems()
        ))
```

which results in only the last batch being written and

```
    csvfile = open('testdump.csv', 'w')

    fieldnames = ['name', 'price']

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)        
    writer.writeheader()        

    csvfile.close()

    for date in date_list:
        date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        q1 = db.session.query(...query goes here that depends on date...)

        rows = []
        for row in q1:
            rows.append(
           {
            'name': row.name,
            'price': row.price,
            }
         )

        csvfile = open('testdump.csv', 'a+')

        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(dict(
            (k, v.encode('utf-8') if type(v) is unicode else v) for k, v in row.iteritems()
        ))

        csvfile.close()
```

which results in only the header being written. Any ideas?

Comment: also, try to debug with some print statements and seeing what result you are getting from the db query.

Answer (score 1):

This example, similarly to your first attempt, creates a properly formatted csv file. We would need to know what the query returns and how the return value is structured to know how to fix it.

```
import csv

with open('testdump.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:

    fieldnames = ['name', 'price']

    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)        
    writer.writeheader()


    rows = [{"name": "apples", "price": "$5"},
            {"name": "oranges", "price": "$4"}]

    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(dict(
       (k, v.encode('utf-8') if type(v) is unicode else v) for k, v in row.iteritems()
    ))
```

The obvious problem with your second attempt is that where you wrote

```
    writer.writerow(dict(
    (k, v.encode('utf-8') if type(v) is unicode else v) for k, v in row.iteritems()
))
```

you were writing to a closed file object and did not create a new writer for the new file object.